# Delete model from Realm

Tags: swift3, realm

I am trying to remove a model from Realm. I appears there's a straightforward way to do it in Java with

```
realm.getSchema().remove(className)
```

It doesn't appear there is an option in Swift 3 other than to remove the model from the App and then migrate the data, or delete the entire Realm file.

To clarify, when I open the Realm Browser I have three models

```
Dog 2
Person 4
Test 0
```

and I want to remove just the Test model via code. There doesn't appear to be any way to remove it via the Browser either.

Perhaps I overlooked something in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you haven't overlooked anything in the docs.

It is not possible to modify the schema of a Realm file in the Objective-C/Swift SDKs without triggering a migration. In which case, you can use [`Migration.deleteData(forType:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration10deleteDataFT7forTypeSS_Sb) to delete the object schema from the Realm.

Additionally, if you want to explicitly ensure that `Test` isn't added to your Realm file in the first place, you can explicitly define that [in your Realm configuration](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:vVC10RealmSwift5Realm13Configuration11objectTypesGSqGSaMCS_6Object__).

Comment: Wow. Not the answer I wanted but an answer none the less. I assume it's not an oversight but having the ability to remove a model would certainly help during development.

Comment: I'm totally there with you. It's something I've wanted for the Realm Browser for a while, but it's very low priority since editing Realms during development isn't a critical user facing feature (Especially when you can simply delete the Realm file). Nevertheless, one of the other Realm engineers is looking into dynamic schema changes this week. :)