# is it possible to rename my realm Models' name?

Tags: realm

[image]

Like above pic, I want to rename ***RealmObject*** to ***WeekRealmObject***, which is more clear for the naming. I tried to search Stackoverflow and check the realm swift documentation and their examples, but it seems only rename or update property values is available through Migration, but not for Models.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: My assumption is that you'd need to migrate the objects from the old schema into objects created in the new schema using a migration, meaning you'd need to create new objects, map over, and delete the old class.

[Docs to migration](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration6createFTSS5valueP__CS_13DynamicObject)

Comment: We tracked such a feature https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2499. Until that will be merged, you can create a new class then copy all data from old class.

Answer (score 3):

I believe, based on an answer to my question about [Deleting A Realm Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696035/delete-model-from-realm), you can't directly change the model name.

However, when a Realm is opened in code, model classes that don't exist are automatically created. So if you were to for example, rename a class, a new representation of the class is created automatically. Unfortunately the objects are not copied, and you will have to add a migration step for that.

The flow would then be to iterate over all of the objects in the old class and create/copy their properties to the new class, then clear the old class.

IMO this is such a basic development function, I don't understand why renaming or deleting models wasn't (isn't) part of the API.

Comment: yeah, agree you. Hope they will make such function more easy

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
realm.getSchema().get("old_object_name").setClassName("new_object_name")
```

Edit:

```
    class Migration implements RealmMigration {
        @Override
        public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

    if(oldVersion==current_realm_database_version)
        realm.getSchema().get("old_object_name").setClassName("new_object_name")

oldVersion++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Where would we use this during migration? The closest I found was `realm.schema.objectSchema["old_object_name"].className`, but `className` is read-only.

Comment: see this improved answer @bcause